# Animation working in animator but not in game

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

The attack animation says that it is running in the animator, but still does the walk animation in the game. It shows the transition and that the attack animation is running, but there is no change in motion in the game.  [Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K9Kf.png)
. As you can see the animator in the bottom window shows that attack is running, but it is not doing the attack animation. If you have any ideas or solutions please let me know, thank you.

Comment: hard to tell from what you showed but you have a Player object and this basicplayer clone.. which seems odd.. in edit mode does triggering that part of the animator make it work properly?

Comment: can you write code how you set your bool value?

Comment: @NikolayGonza I changed it to a boolean instead of  trigger, but my code is animator.SetBool("Attack", true);

Comment: @BugFinder the Player object is just the test dummy for collisions, and basicplayer clone is the prefab of the main player. I'm not sure what you mean by " in edit mode does triggering that part of the animator make it work properly?". I'm kinda new to Unity, so if you don't mind can you clarify please and thank you.